# Price vs. quantity calculations in a Foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to calculate the total price per line, by inserting my products from an SQL database.

With the piece of code I made, I can calculate the total if I have only one product in my database. The problem is that I can't have several id attributes with the same name, I know that.

How would it be possible to calculate the total in javascript, and in my HTML code to increment the id qty and price?

This is my code :

```
<?php
include 'main.php';
check_loggedin($pdo);
$minerals = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = "mineral"');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    </head>
    <body class="loggedin">
        <?php include 'navigation.php' ;?>
        <main>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Caisse</h2>
                <div class="content-block">
                    <form action="" method="post" class="">
                        <div class="table">
                            <h3>Minérales</h3>
                            
                            <table>
                                <colgroup>
                                    <col width="5%">
                                    <col width="35%">
                                    <col width="20%">
                                    <col width="20%">
                                    <col width="20%">
                                </colgroup>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>QTY</td>
                                        <td class="center">Product</td>
                                        <td>Unit</td>
                                        <td>Price</td>
                                        <td>Total</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php if (!$minerals): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">There are no minerals</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($minerals as $mineral): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty_mineral" oninput="Calcul_total()"></td>
                                        <td class="center"><?=$mineral['name']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$mineral['unit']?></td>
                                        <td id="price"><?=$mineral['price']?></td>
                                        <td id="total"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    
    function Calcul_total() {
        var x = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        var y = document.getElementById('price').textContent;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = x * y;
    }
</script>
```

I think I either need to be able to increment the qty & price id for each . But I don't see how to do it in php.

And for the calculation in javascript, I would need to be able to get those id increment to do the total. But I don't see how to do it.

So if you could point me in the right direction, I already thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your function `Calcul_total` to know on which table line it should operate you need a way for it know the context when it gets called.

The quickest way that would easily fit in your scenario, is to call that function passing the argument `this`.

So that the function later will focus on that line only instead of querying the whole document while searching for the elements `.qty`, `.price` and `.total`. As you can see I changed your strategy to use the same id for elements repeating on each row, so I preferred to use the class approach instead because id are expected to be unique in the whole document.

I picked part of your code to show the concept (using two lines only for gold and silver):

```js
function Calcul_total(target) {
  const parent = target.closest('tr');
  var x = parent.querySelector('.qty').value;
  var y = parent.querySelector('.price').textContent;
  parent.querySelector('.total').innerText = x * y;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="">
  <div class="table">
    <h3>Minérales</h3>

    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col width="5%">
        <col width="35%">
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>QTY</td>
          <td class="center">Product</td>
          <td>Unit</td>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="qty"
              oninput="Calcul_total(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="center">Gold</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td class="price">57.22</td>
          <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="qty"
              oninput="Calcul_total(this)">
          </td>
          <td class="center">Silver</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td class="price">35.53</td>
          <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tested and everything works perfectly. Once I have the solution in front of me, it seems simple.

Thank you very much for your help, and for the quick response.